# How to float navbar menu in Bootstrap to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a navbar with bootstrap that contains a navigation menu & a button. 
The navigation menu is floating to left side and button is on the right side. I want to change their position so the menu would stick to right side & the button would be on the left side. Please help me how to do such thing.. Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Wiredwiki</a>
        </div><!-- Navbar Header -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-right">Download Now</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Container -->
</nav><!-- End Navbar -->
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse">
    <a href="" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-left">Download Now</a>
```

I hope the above code works for you. I have made navbar-right for the whole div, navbar-left for the button.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of `navbar-left` and `navbar-right`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="my-navbar">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="" class="navbar-brand">Wiredwiki</a>
        </div><!-- Navbar Header -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
        <a href="" class="btn btn-warning navbar-btn navbar-left">Download Now</a>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#feedback">Feedback</a></li>
                <li><a href="#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
                <li><a href="#faq">Faq</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>               
        </div>
    </div><!-- End Container -->
</nav><!-- End Navbar -->
```